# How to uniquely identify a table row?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, html-table

In my app I import a JSON file and then display it in a table. The table has 3 columns.

Two issues with this:

1. The table also has sorting and CRUD operations, so [using the array index for the row key is not best practice](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md).
2. Similar with above, I am trying to implement the functionality to edit a row, and doing so by index is finicky because they may have shifted from sorting or CRUD.

I came up with some potential solutions, but they all seem weak:

1. Uniquely identify a row by a combination of its visible columns. This has problems because while it's extremely unlikely there will be duplicate rows for this data set, I suppose it's possible.
2. Uniquely identify a row by fields that are relatively guaranteed to be unique. For example, each row has a creation date, and since all rows are generated manually in the program, I believe this could function as an ID for uniquely identifying rows? It kinda feels like identifying a row by a date is bad for some reason though.. Not sure.
3. Uniquely identify a row by a combination of all its fields (visible and hidden). May be slow or needlessly complex?
4. Upon row creation, assign an ID to the row that isn't shown to the user and is persisted in the saved file. Would also probably need to have a global counter variable saved (because if a row is deleted we wouldn't want to re-use that ID and we need to know where we left off from).
5. Assign a GUID to each row? Wouldn't need to store an index counter but more space would be required (although the files are relatively small so I'm not sure how much  this matters).

Are there any other or better ways that I'm missing? How is this normally handled?

Comment: You named all the techniques already, One other option I think of is to hash the columns with some random value as salt and use that as key. But that's not much different that using `GUID`s for this specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with 4 or 5, but with a minor change:

You can keep the JSON as is. Upon **importing** the JSON, you map each item and assign them an `ID` or `GUID` - I'd use `ID` for simplicity, but it's up to you. Within the execution of your program, this field will be used to the CRUD operations and/or sorting.

When your program is done, map again your data, and save back in the same format you've received (removing the new prop you've added).